# My Model form for Django is not saving because it's invalid but I can't see what's wrong

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-2.0

I'm very new to Django and part of the assignment was to create our own blog model form. I followed the previous examples of the youtube tutorial but was unable to create my own blog model form. The form will not save because it's invalid and I have been busting my head for 2 days to solve it but can't find what is wrong.

Also, every time I submit my form, it redirects me to another page which I don't quite understand why.

Please help.

I'm using Django version 2.0.7.

My models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):
    title   = models.CharField(max_length=120) # Max length required
    content = models.TextField()
    active  = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

My forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import Article

class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = [
            'title',
            'content',
            'active'
        ]
```

my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from .forms import ArticleForm
from .models import Article

def article_list_view(request):
    print("this is article_list.html")
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    context ={
        "object_list": queryset
    }
    return render(request, "blogs/article_list.html", context)

def article_create_view(request):
    form = ArticleForm(request.POST or None)
    print(ArticleForm.errors)
    if form.is_valid():
        print("Valid form")
        form.save()
    else:
        print("invalid")
        print(ArticleForm.errors)
    context = {
        "form": form
    }
    return render(request, "blogs/article_create.html", context)
```

article_create.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

    <form action='.' method='POST'>{% csrf_token %} 
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type='submit' value='Save'>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

from pages.views import (
    home_view, 
    contact_view, 
    about_view, 
    social_view
    )

from blog.views import (
    article_list_view, 
    article_detail_view,
    article_create_view
    )

urlpatterns = [
    path('products/', include('products.urls')),

    path('', home_view, name='home'),
    path('contact/', contact_view, name='contact'),
    path('about/', about_view, name='product-detail'),
    path('social/', social_view, name='social'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    #blog paths
    path('articles/', article_list_view, name = 'articles'),
    path('articles/detail/<int:id>', article_detail_view, name = 'article-detail'),
    path('articles/create', article_create_view, name = 'article-create'),

]
```

This shows up on my command prompt of my server:

```
Django version 2.0.7, using settings 'trydjango.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
<property object at 0x000001ED94386458>
invalid
<property object at 0x000001ED94386458>
[18/Apr/2019 22:33:51] "GET /articles/create HTTP/1.1" 200 920
this is article_list.html
[18/Apr/2019 22:34:02] "POST /articles/ HTTP/1.1" 200 668
```

As soon as I land onto the articles/create or article_create.html, the `<property object at 0x000001ED94386458>` shows up.

Comment: You need get form in article_list_view, not in create

Answer (score 0):

1) You should not use `.errors` on the *class*.

```
ArticleForm.errors
```

should be

```
form.errors
```

2) You should separate your GET and POST requests in your view.

```
def article_create_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ArticleForm(request.POST)            
        if form.is_valid():
            print("Valid form")
            form.save()
        else:
            print("Invalid form")
            print(form.errors)        
    else:
        form = ArticleForm()

    context = {"form": form)

    return render(request, "blogs/article_create.html", context)
```

Comment: Thanks but that did not make a difference. My command prompt window shows the following now: ```Django version 2.0.7, using settings 'trydjango.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[18/Apr/2019 23:13:40] "GET /articles/create HTTP/1.1" 200 920
this is article_list.html```

Answer (score 0):

Your form should be posting to `""`, not `"."`.

```
<form action='' method='POST'>{% csrf_token %}
```

Alternatively/additionally, make sure you originally navigate to `/articles/create/`, not `/articles/create` without the final slash. (Although normally the built-in CommonMiddleware will take care of redirecting to the path with the slash - have you set the APPEND_SLASH setting to False by any chance? Don't.)

Comment: I wish I read this comment 33 mins earlier :) I just figured that part out as well. You are correct, it was my ```<form action = '' method='POST'>{% csrf_token %}```. I will look into that slash issue you mentioned. I don't think i'm quite there yet on the tutorials :)

Comment: I understand what you meant by the ```/articles/create/``` url now. Got it, I made the adjustment on the urls.py to ```/articles/create/``` instead of ```/articles/create``` without the slash. I was able to add the . back into ```<form action='.' method='POST'>{% csrf_token %}``` and everything works. Thanks again!!! I was stuck for 2 days!